# Custom function error timezone localizing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert the string to DateTime and set timezone local via a custom function.

`x` is Pandas Series

```
def tz_localize(x):
    x = pd.Series(x, dtype='str')
    x = pd.to_datetime(x)
    x = x.dt.tz_localize(tz='EST',ambiguous='infer')
    return x
```

timezone localize is not working. There is no error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert timezone

```
x = x.dt.tz_localize(tz='EST').dt.tz_convert('Asia/Kolkata')
return x
```

refrence- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html

Comment: No, it is not working. I don't want to convert just to localize

Comment: The issue is with the custom function. If I apply directly in the pandas series it is working fine.